# Is there a regex to match letters exept vowels using only one hook []?

Tags: regex

The regex I want would match any string with only letters, but no vowel inside it. But I want to do it using only one `[]`. The regex has to match a range like `a-z` and negate an other group like `aeiou`.

It would match:

```
pfbnzb
gpmrq
thgrt  
pmmrrjhgz  
mpll
```

And not:

```
azertyui  
aouie  
halapala  
pldhuddgr
```

The regex I have now is:

```
^((?![aeiou])[a-z])+$
```

The regex with one `[]` is :

```
^[a-z^aeiou]+$
```

But the `^` is a considered as a character if not the first one in `[]`.

Comment: Sure, just write it out: `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` or even `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]`

Comment: I wanted a regex to match a range, and not match an other one in the hook, I will edit

Comment: Just fyi - "*letters except vowels*" are called consonants :)

Comment: ahah yes it's true, yet I wanted the logic as I said to match all letters and then exclude voyels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just add all the possible letters to your character class, like

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]
```

or with a few ranges

```
[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]
```

There are some regex engines that do support different kinds of character class substractions, like .net `[a-z-[aeiou]]` and Java `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]`, but it's not a common feature.

Comment: So with the classic regex it's not possible I guess ?

Comment: There is nothing like a _classic_ regex, just a multitude of different implementations for different languages or tools. If you name the regex engine you are using, one could tell.

Comment: I usually try my regex in js or with online tool like regex101.com

Comment: Neither JS nor PCRE (the regex101 default) have that feature.

Answer (score 0):

> The regex with one [] is : ^[a-z^aeiou]+$

A character class (`[...]`) is either including (when the first symbol in it is not `^`) or excluding (when the first symbol it contains is `^`). It cannot be both.

One character class that contains all letters but the vowels is `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`.